# Flexbox doesn't shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning flex box in css. I have banner in my html code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: seashell;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 69px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
}

/* ------- Banner styles ------- */
#banner {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 1 700px;
    background-image: url('https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg?_gl=1*fa57o6*_ga*Njc4NzQ5NjE2My4xNjg3MTA0MTk5*_ga_3LRZM6TM9L*MTY4OTMwMjg1NS4xNS4xLjE2ODkzMDY0NzQuNTMuMC4w');
}

#banner div {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 15%;
    flex: 0 1 15%;
}

#banner h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article id="banner">
    <div>
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range,  Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

I expect it to shrink when changing window size, but it doesn't happen.
I thought it should work, since flex-shrink property is 1, and flex-basis is 700px. As far as I understand, it means that initially length along main flex axis will be 700px, and then will shrink if one changes window size. Why am I wrong?
(I am using Safari)

Comment: I viewed this in Chrome Version 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it shrank when the window size shrank... So no repro in that browser, on Windows 10 Version 22H2.

Comment: Current Safari / OSX also shows `#banner` adjusting to window size appropriately when below 700px.   Are you maybe expecting the background image to scale down along with it instead of being cropped? (If so look at the various options for `background-size`, one of them should suit)

Comment: @DanielBeck i am using Safari too, but I don't see even text to shrink. I edited question, added <main> tag and styles from my code, probably it makes a difference

Comment: Using `* { opacity: 0.9; }` is a bad idea for _so many_ reasons...

Comment: Off-topic-tip: When using `display: flex` or `display: grid` for a parent, you should prefer the child-combinator `>` in your selector instead of the descendant-combinator (whitespace), as flex and grid impact only immediate children, not descendants (unless you're using `display: contents`), so change `#banner div` to `#banner > div`.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for tip! Didn't know that! But this didn't solve a problem (

Comment: @Vladyslav Can you tell me which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam Version 16.4 (18615.1.26.110.1)

Comment: Then it may not be a cross-browser issue.

Comment: Can you try this? ```#banner {max-width: 999px; min-height: 700px;}``` and hide this one ```flex: 1 1 700px; ``` Just for debugging purpose? Because it is the only property that can prevent the text from wrapping.

Comment: learning css in safari is sin use Firefox it will great for CSS show flex/gird/more.Safari have many unusual things. After 4 Year CSS still Safari still cause many sufferings. If you committed to Safari use tailwind.